# Usage of timer may be slowing my application down

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm writing an app that will have a list of "active alarms" for users to interact with in various ways. Each timer is represented by an object that contains a "created time" that represents when the alarm came into existence. I have a fragment that displays all of the alarms to a user, where each Alarm is represented as a RelativeLayout with a TextView containing the "age" of a timer, where age is calculated by the created time subtracted from the current time. The requirements for my application state that the age needs to be calculated and updated once every second.

Here's the code for my timer:

```
final Handler myHandler = new Handler();

    final Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable(){

        public void run()
        {
            alarmDuration.setText("Age: " + tempAlarm.getAge());
        }
    };



    try {
        //This timer is meant to update the time on each Alarm once a second.
        Timer timer = new Timer();

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                myHandler.post(myRunnable);
            }

        };
        //Schedule the timer to go every second.
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 0, 1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Each alarm view has its own Handler, Runnable, and Timer. Here's where my problem lies: When I am displaying less than 10 of these timers, the app seems to run fine and can manage the updating with no problem. However, I tried loading somewhere in the realm of 100 alarms, and the application began to drop frames (as seen in my console). On configuration change (such as rotating the screen), I was getting dropped frames in the realm of 50-60.

Is this a good way to update these textViews or is there a method that would create less of a drag on the application? One idea I had was to possible put the IDs of all the alarm age views into an ArrayList and then have just one Handler, Runnable, and Timer to update the entire list.

Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: dont use Timers/TimerTasks, simple Handler will do the trick

Comment: How can I use a Handler to run a timed task? And should I use a handler for every alarm, or one handler to handle all of the alarms?

Comment: one Handler is enough,  just use "delayed" methods

Comment: Side note: you shouldn't update your TextViews like this bacause it's a non-UI thread.

Comment: Gumbo what method should I use?